# IE: Show ul>li>ul on hover

Tags: css, internet-explorer, nav

I struggle to make the navigation on this site work in IE:
http://test3.grysom.cz

The intended behavior is to show the whole navigation whenever one hovers over the `nav` element

It isn't working even when I strip the code down to this:

```
ul#main-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}


nav.main ul>li>ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    min-height: 1px;
}

nav.main:hover ul>li>ul, nav.main:focus-within ul>li>ul {
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: 999px;
}
```

It works in most current browsers but not in the older ones. And since I'm pretty much amateur I can't really think of any reason why.

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: If you depend on *:focus-within*, there's not a lot of browser support for it https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Afocus-within

Comment: I realize it is not optimal to use it. On the other hand, :hover is the core functionality I depend on here. :focus-within is added just to enhance the accessibility a bit more for people who can't use cursor. Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers ignore rulesets containing invalid selectors. For IE, `nav.main:focus-within ul>li>ul` is an invalid selector due to `:focus-within`. So just split your two rules:

```
nav.main:hover ul>li>ul {
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: 999px;
}
nav.main:focus-within ul>li>ul {
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: 999px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, exactly the detail I've suspected myself to be missing out. Thank you very much! You saved me from smashing my head into the laptop out of frustration.